# CSS - Implementing a border image with tab

Tags: html, border, css

More a back end programmer, but I'm implementing a design, and I just wanted to see what the most efficient way of implementing a border box would be.

Here is an example of the box -

[image: border box]

The idea is that the blue tab will contain the header text for the section.

Ideally I'd like to use just HTML and CSS, but I realise I may need to use the tab as an image because of it's shape. These boxes can be numerous sizes depending on the content.

I could do the blue border no problem using

```
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px;
```

or similar, it's mainly the tab that poses the issue for me. Has anyone done anything similar that can offer advice?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Start here](http://jsfiddle.net/pwTVz/)** and modify as you need, should work for what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
.tab-header {
  background: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px; /* we extend the header by 10px to the bottom */
}

.tab-body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: white; /* set a solid background */
  margin-top: -10px; /* move the body 10px up, so it covers the
                        10px padding from above */
}
```

You must prefix the border-radius stuff accordingly, but apart from that this should work in any recent browser.